How can I list files in a folder based on version number?
I have a folder containing .txt files named like the following:
A_COR_001_I
A_COR_001_II
A_COR_002_I
A_COR_002_II
A_COR_003_I
A_COR_003_II
A_COR_003_III
A_COR_004_I
A_COR_004_II
A_COR_004_III
A_COR_004_IV
...

The roman numerals at the end of each string signify the definitive draft of a distinct document, identified by the preceding arabic numbers, like 002. I am trying to extract only the final drafts with a regex pattern using a list.files() function, but the problem is that each document has an unpredictable number of drafts, so I would need a way to group together the drafts of each document and single out the ones with the highest number, so A_COR_004_IV instead of A_COR_004_III or any other. Any ideas on how to proceed? Thanks in advance!

Base R has an as.roman() function which allows Simple manipulation of... roman numerals.
So split the files into lists by filename based on what appears before the last underscore (i.e. "A_COR_001" to "A_COR_004") then find the element with the max() roman numeral (i.e. max numeric value after the final underscore).
split(files, sub("_[^_]+$", "", files)) |>
    lapply(
        \(l) l[which.max(as.roman(sub(".*_", "", l)))]
    )
# $A_COR_001
# [1] "A_COR_001_II"

# $A_COR_002
# [1] "A_COR_002_II"

# $A_COR_003
# [1] "A_COR_003_III"

# $A_COR_004
# [1] "A_COR_004_IV"

I imagine this will not be a problem here but note that the docs state:

Only numbers between 1 and 3999 have a unique representation as roman numbers, and hence others result in as.roman(NA).

Interestingly, this is actually just structure(NA_integer_, class = "roman").
Incidentally, list.files() will return the results in lexicographic order, which if you have at most 8 versions of all files is the order that you want (until IX). So you can just do lapply(split(files, sub("_[^_]+$", "", files)), tail, 1).
Data
files <- c( "A_COR_001_I", "A_COR_001_II", "A_COR_002_I", "A_COR_002_II", "A_COR_003_I", "A_COR_003_II", "A_COR_003_III", "A_COR_004_I", "A_COR_004_II", "A_COR_004_III", "A_COR_004_IV" )


This worked for me, thank you very much also for the additional info!

Something like:
f <- c("A_COR_001_I", "A_COR_001_II", "A_COR_002_I", "A_COR_002_II", "A_COR_003_I", "A_COR_003_II", "A_COR_003_III", "A_COR_004_I", "A_COR_004_II", "A_COR_004_III", "A_COR_004_IV")

f |> as.data.frame() |>
  dplyr::mutate(number = stringr::str_extract(pattern = "\\d+", f), 
                roman = as.numeric(as.roman(stringi::stri_extract_last_regex(pattern = "[A-Z]+", f)))) |>
  dplyr::arrange(number, dplyr::desc(roman)) |>
  dplyr::group_by(number) |>
  dplyr::filter(dplyr::row_number()==1)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   number [4]
#>   f             number roman
#>   <chr>         <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 A_COR_001_II  001        2
#> 2 A_COR_002_II  002        2
#> 3 A_COR_003_III 003        3
#> 4 A_COR_004_IV  004        4

Created on 2024-10-01 with reprex v2.1.0

Assuming that the file names are not necessarily in any particular order,
define

stem as the substring up to the last underscore and
ver as the version number converted to numeric.

Then extract the filenames having the largest version for its stem.
This uses only base R, is vectorized and does not use *apply.
stem <- trimws(files, "right", "[^_]")
ver <- as.integer(as.roman(sub(".*_", "", files)))
files[ave(ver, stem, FUN = max) == ver]
## [1] "A_COR_001_II"  "A_COR_002_II"  "A_COR_003_III" "A_COR_004_IV" 

If it were known that the files are already sorted, as is the case in the
question, then this would do:
tapply(files, trimws(files, "right", "[^_]"), tail, 1)
##      A_COR_001_      A_COR_002_      A_COR_003_      A_COR_004_ 
##  "A_COR_001_II"  "A_COR_002_II" "A_COR_003_III"  "A_COR_004_IV" 

Note
files <- c("A_COR_001_I", "A_COR_001_II", "A_COR_002_I", "A_COR_002_II", 
  "A_COR_003_I", "A_COR_003_II", "A_COR_003_III", "A_COR_004_I", 
  "A_COR_004_II", "A_COR_004_III", "A_COR_004_IV")

